# Equivalence relation example

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

On the Wikipedia page about Equivalence Relations, there is a [simple example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Simple_example):

> Let the set $\{a,b,c\}$ have the equivalence relation $\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c),(b,c),(c,b)\}$. The following sets are equivalence classes of this relation:
>
> $[a]=\{a\},~~~~~[b]=[c]=\{b,c\}$.
>
> The set of all equivalence classes for this relation is $\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$.

I don't understand why $\{c,b\}$ is not an equivalence class as well as $\{b,c\}$.

Furthermore, if $[a]=\{a\}$, then shouldn't the same hold for $[b]=\{b\}$ and $[c]=\{c\}$ since $\{b,b\}$ and $\{c,c\}$ are both in the relation?

---

**Edit**

After more thought, I've realised that my confusion may be to do with not understanding the notation properly. Is the Wikipedia article stating the $b$ and $c$ are equivalent (which would mean that $\{b,c\}$ and $\{c,b\}$ are the same)?

Comment: How would you interpret $\{c,b\}$ to be an equivalence relation? An equivalence relation, when defined formally, is a subset of the *cartesian product* of a set by itself and $\{c,b\}$ is not such a set in an obvious way.

Comment: I meant to say equivalence *class*, not equivalence *relation* on the line after the quote. I've updated my question, sorry!

Comment: Your confusion is more basic. The **sets** $\{b,c\}$ and $\{c,b\}$ are the same. This is because a set is an unordered object.

Comment: The wikipedia implicitly states that it is an equivalence class for this relation by stating “The set of all equivalence classes for this relation is $\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$”, which means the equivalence classes are $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c\}$.

Oh. That was your confusion. Yes, $\{b,c\} = \{c,b\}$ since two sets are by definiton if equal if and only if they hold the same elements (no matter how often or in which order you write them: $\{1,1,3,1,2\} = \{2,3,1\}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces denote sets, so the order does not matter, ie. $\{b,c\}=\{c,b\}$. There is a difference between an equivalence *relation* and the equivalence *classes*. The relation is an ordered pair $(a,b)$, which means that $a$ and $b$ are equivalent.

The equivalence class is the set of all equivalent elements, so in your example, you have $[b]=[c]=\{b,c\}=\{c,b\}$. But it is not true that $[b]=\{b\}$, since $\{b\}\neq\{b,c\}$ (instead you could write $b\in [b]$).